# WCF error: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to access WCF service from a server to my client web application for testing. I am getting the following error:

The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security

I am using wsHttpBinding.

and

```
<bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IVirtualMachineManagementService"
     closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
     sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
     maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
     useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
     <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
      enabled="false" />
     <security mode="Message">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
       algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
     </security>
    </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
        <client>
   <endpoint address="http://173.192.138.18/SCVMMService/VirtualMachineManagementService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IVirtualMachineManagementService"
    contract="ServiceReference1.IVirtualMachineManagementService"
    name="WSHttpBinding_IVirtualMachineManagementService">
    <identity>
     <servicePrincipalName value="host/win48.scvmmrc.ourcp.com" />
    </identity>
   </endpoint>
  </client>
```

Comment: What makes you believe it's something specific to WCF?  From the error you posted, it sounds like your client or service was trying to write to the Security event viewer and ran into a permission issue.

Comment: Like @Tim says, this is indeed the problem: at some point you're trying to write something to the security-log. I suggest you look into that direction, to pinpoint the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that you are connecting to the right DB with right credentials for logging; or if using file as source for logging then check if the user which is running the code has write permissions to the file its trying to use for loging.

Comment: It's not a database, its the Windows Event Logs - the error OP reports is "The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security".  This has nothing to do with databases or file logging.